# Chrome Dev Tools Default Mobile Device List update?

Tags: web-development, chrome

Chrome's Dev Tools has a default list of devices for mobile development, but does Google ever update the list? I'm guessing not, since the devices are getting ancient by internet standards (iPhone 5s? Really?).

My main question - is there an app or extension that provides a more updated list of mobile devices to Chrome Dev tools? I know I can add my own individually, but frankly, that's a pain, since there are many devices out there. And while I know that various websites do simulations for each device, it's difficult to develop against them using dev tools. Help?

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that the devices are not really emulated. If you have a specific bug on a device, you won't be able to identify it with Chrome Dev Tools. Read more in the [google docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/). I recommend [remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/) with a real device (for me it is sometimes the only way to reproduce bug reports)! Or using something as [browser stack](https://www.browserstack.com/) (which allows testing on real devices).